# Lagrange's formula for the remainder

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), Lagrange's formula for the remainder term $R_k$ of a Taylor polynomial is given by

$$R_{k}(x)=\frac{f^{(k+1)}\left(\xi_{L}\right)}{(k+1) !}(x-a)^{k+1}$$

for some $\xi_L$ between $a$ and $x$.

But if find this last condition a little ambiguous: can $\xi_L$ be equal to $a$ or $x$?

Comment: No. The theorem on this residue clearly states that $\;\xi\;$ is between $\;a\,,\,\,x\;$ and not equal to them. This follows from basic theorems of differentiable functions...

Comment: And you'll use that ambiguity in the Lagrange form to estimate that residue...!

Comment: Just to be clear, it can happen that $f^{(k+1)}(\xi_L)=f^{(k+1)}(a)$ (or $f^{(k+1)}(x)$) but that is not the same as $\xi_L=a$ (or $x$).

Answer (score 2):

It cannot. It is actually $\xi_L \in (a,x)$.

To say why, the way Taylor's theorem with Lagranges's form of remainder is proved, is by using Rolle's Theorem :- $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous on $[a,b]$, and $f(a)=f(b)$, then $\exists \xi \in$ "$(a,b)$" such that $f'(\xi)=0$.

Note the open interval.

Comment: So, if $a<x$, then $\xi_L \in (a,x)$ and, if $a>x$, then $\xi_L \in (x,a)$?

Comment: Purely dependant on how you define $f$. To be specific, $f:[\min (a,x),\max (a,x) ]\to \mathbb R$ must be $n-$times differentiable on $(\min (a,x), \max (a,x) )$ and continuous at $a,x$ as well (to apply Rolle)

Comment: (+1) from me @Shamim :)